# SoapUI Office 365 REST API creating task and meeting

Tags: rest, office365, soapui, office365api

I need to create a meeting and tasks from SoapUI to act as testdata for an application build internally.

I have gone through many articles and a couple of them from Stack Overflow, but I didn't get the answer or right approach.

I have my username, password and app/client id, and below are the questions.

1. How do I pass an app/client id in the SoapUI request?
2. Is there anything else I would require to access the API?
3. Is there any step-by-step help available for SoapUI to access the Office API?

More details:

In the SoapUI when I click on auth, I get the below screenshot:

[image: SoapUI image]

As this is the core SoapUI test which mean I am going to consume Office 365 in SoapUI, not in any application, what should I enter in authorization URI, accesstoken URI, redirect URI?

Comment: Have you checked office documentation for the same?

Comment: I am looking solution from SOAPUI for QA, although office api has documentation which are more from development

Comment: You need to use that documentation on how to make calls.

Comment: Rao,

there is lot difference between the implementation model of soapui and documentation, before posting question i did review documentation and couple of others as mentioned in the question

Comment: how do i pass app/client id in the soapui request

Comment: Rao, The question is mainly on implementing office365 API through soap ui. As mentioned earlier, i have username/password, client id and i am looking for solution in integrating these details in soapui and also also looking for a implementation of creating meeting though soapui.

This question is more for the soapui developers are some one who has used soapui and office 365